# Javascript Regex multiple characters split

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to Split complete document made out of text to separate words,how can I do this so it gives me each word alone , 
I used .Split function and It worked for the white space character , other than that no , 
I need a regex that can split the words based on (`.` and `,` and `|` and `:` and `;` and `,`)

any help ?

Comment: Show your code and some examples.

Comment: `yourStringValue.split(/[.,|:;,]/);`

Comment: You could replace all of the those characters with white space, the perform the split.

Comment: ok try: `yourStringValue.split(/[.,|:;, ]/g);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = "This; is my text. With|all,characters: to split,";
var arr = text.split(/[.|:;\s]/);
```

The `[.,|:;,\s]` is a character class, which contains all characters on which you want to split. `\s` indicates any whitespace (spaces, tabs ...).